# Lookup between 2 related models in django form

Tags: python, django, lookup

I have 2 models: Company and Contact. Relation is one to many. I want to create a form in the way that in the beginning, the selectbox "company" is fullfilled with all data from database and selectbox "contact" is empty. Every time the selectbox "company" chooses a new company, the selectbox "contact" fullfills automatically with the contacts of the current company. I'm using django 1.4.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_type = models.ForeignKey('CompanyType', on_delete=models.PROTECT) 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='', blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='', blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='', blank=True)
    postcode = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='', blank=True)

class Contact(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='')
    letterhead = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='',blank=True)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='',blank=True)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='',blank=True)
    mobile_phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='',blank=True)
    job = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='',blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, default='',blank=True, validators=[validate_email])
    fax = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='',blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField()  

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Well, you can do that with Ajax. What's your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Daniel said, your best solution is Ajax, each time the user select a company, you get the select value, make an ajax request and insert the data in the forum. You have to use JS !